# On windows 7(x64), C++ run in Netbeans 8.1 hangs during RUN

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I have above mentioned set up and I am running Hello world program.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compile and build are successful but the execution hangs. See bottom right of the picture.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a Tech Support question. Please migrate.

Comment: It would be [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Hi how to do that? Shall I just delete this one and add new in Superuser?

Comment: I've flagged your question. A moderator should be migrating it.

Comment: Regarding "See bottom right of the picture." I don't see any picture.

Comment: It might be helpful to try the different terminal types in Properties -> Run -> Console Type. Perhaps it is trying to start an external console and can not.